# Input data in VBA TextBox and reflect it to Google Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to create a simple form using Excel VBA with just plain text boxes and a submit button.

This is what I want:

When I fill up textboxes some info then I click the submit button, it will directly be inputted to 1 row in google sheet and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you mean by having a form on excel that populates in google forms. Do you want it to dynamically update? if not then you can accomplish it with a pretty simple code 
you would need to create a userform on the developer tab->Visual Basics. Once you create the userform you can add textboxes and a button to click OK. when you alter the code for what actions to complete when the OK button is clicked you can do:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Cells(1, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
Cells(2, 1).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
Cells(3, 1).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

if you provide more information about what the program is being used for/how it is being used or a sample file then I may be able to provide a more detailed/better answer. Hope this helps

Comment: Data from TextBox1 and TextBox2 will be inputted or populated to specific row&column on google sheet when I hit the commandbutton/